# How I can see who watched my Strava profile?

Tags: strava

I have strava account,
Can I somehow see who watched my strava profile or my strava activities?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Strava, not Bikes

Comment: You mean other than the CIA and the Ruskies?  (This is really a question about Internet/phone security.  The place to start would be either [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: Don't forget to join the Strava SE Bicycles club.    https://www.strava.com/clubs/SEBicycles

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.  You can only see who is following you, not who is just looking at your profile/rides.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  While correct, you could improve this answer (making it authoritative) if you could link to an official source (on Strava) that explained the details of who can see what.

Comment: Thanks DavidW. I will do that

Answer (score 1):

Its kinda off topic because its a software question, but the software is used for cycling by a lot of people.

Visit

> https://www.strava.com/athletes/YOURNUMBER/follows?type=followers

where YOURNUMBER is your strava user ID.

You can also find the same info by going to "My Profile" in the upper right menu, then click the third tab labelled "Following" which is under any photos you have recently shared.  Then choose "Following Me" from the dropdown box.

Either way, you can see who is following you, and whether you follow them back or not.

Its a current snapshot too, someone who has unfollowed you will not be listed.

Comment: I think the question is on who visited my profile or saw my activities recently than who follow me - something similar to what we can see in LinkedIn.

Comment: No there's nothing like that.  If you're concerned then check out the privacy settings and make sure that only people you allow to follow you.  That way only people who you permit, can see your rides.

Comment: If you're concerned about who is following you, check your rear view mirror.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Just ride faster and drop them